# Grails scaffolding template

Tags: grails

I'm using Grails 1.37 with Netbeans. When I generate the scaffolding how do I only generate the form in the GSP, not the grails logo etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grails generate-views yourpackage.yourDomainClass` to generate the views only

Use `grails generate-controller yourpackage.yourDomainClass` to generate the controller with full crud actions

Use `grails generate-all yourpackage.yourDomainClass` to do the both commands above

If you want to customise the scaffold engine, take a look on the `src/templates/scaffolding` directory

May this help.

Comment: I cannot find src/templates/scaffolding

Comment: you must execute grails install-templates first, hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

grails generate-view com.package.Domain

Comment: Does this create the methods in the controller too?

Comment: How to genearate methods too? I only don't want the css etc

Comment: grails generate-controller com.package.Domain. If you don't want the css stuff, you can edit gsp files and remove the code about css and logo in layout/main.gsp.